Aws sdk s3 to s3 copyObject checksum is null in CopyObjectResponse
When doing a s3 to s3 copy using aws sdk, I want to save the returned checksum from CopyObjectResponse, so that I can use it later to verify if file is modified or not
but checksum value returned is null
fun CopyObjectResponse.toCopyResponseModel(): CopyResponse =
    CopyResponse(
        etag = this.copyObjectResult().eTag(),
        isSuccessFull = this.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful,
        statusCode = this.sdkHttpResponse().statusCode(),
        checksum = this.copyObjectResult().checksumSHA256()
    )

how can i get checksum?
I can copy at max 5gb file in a singlePartCopy wondering can we use etag or not, will have to figure out multipart too since it changes on each copy even though the file is not modified

It's not clear, which AWS SDK you are using (boto3?). What does copyObjectResult() do exactly, especially checksumSHA256()? Did you implement these functions?

Based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObjectResult.html, the checksum seems to be optional.

Do you pass the checksum/algorithm in the CopyObject request? If not, then it also will not be part of the response (optional, as @tevemadar pointed out). To check for integrity, see here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html
